# How to pass multiple MySQL Queries in AWS Lambda Function at once

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, node-mysql

I have a multiple MySQL queries created in Workbench. This query runs by one trigger only in Workbench. I would like this query to be embedded to my AWS Lambda Function but to no avail. I suspect that it is because it multiple queries at the same time.

Here's the code that I created but failed:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
       host     : config.dbhost,
       user     : config.dbuser,
       password : config.dbpassword,
       database : config.dbname
    });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      // Use the connection
      connection.query('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_table; \
                        CREATE VIEW view_table AS \
                            SELECT table3.field1, table1.field2 \
                            FROM table1 \
                            JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id \
                            JOIN table3 ON table1.table3_id = table3.id \
                            JOIN table4 ON item_var.table4_id = table4.id \
                            WHERE item_var.list_id = ? \
                            ORDER BY table1 ASC LIMIT 3 \
                        SELECT table4.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 0, 1) AS field4, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 1, 1) AS field5, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 2, 1) AS field6 \
                        FROM table2 \
                        JOIN table4 ON table2.id = table4.id \
                        WHERE table2.id = ?', event['param1'], function (error, results, fields) {
      // And done with the connection.
      connection.release();
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error) ;
      else callback(null, results);
    });
  });
};
```

And here's the error message I got:

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE VIEW view_table SELECT table3.field1,' at line 1",
```

I suspect the reason for this is Lambda does not accept multiple MySQL queries at the same time.

There are options I got here like,

1. To use AWS SNS Notifications; or
2. Create multiple lambda and trigger them one over the other.

Can anyone guide me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely down to MySQL not supporting multi query, from what I can see you have 2 queries.

You should **not** try running in parallel based on what you've provided as you cannot guarantee the order, why not instead just perform as two seperate queries such as below.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
       host     : config.dbhost,
       user     : config.dbuser,
       password : config.dbpassword,
       database : config.dbname
    });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      // Use the connection
      connection.query('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_table;', function (error, results, fields) {
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error) ;
    });
      connection.query('CREATE VIEW view_table AS \
                            SELECT table3.field1, table1.field2 \
                            FROM table1 \
                            JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id \
                            JOIN table3 ON table1.table3_id = table3.id \
                            JOIN table4 ON item_var.table4_id = table4.id \
                            WHERE item_var.list_id = ? \
                            ORDER BY table1 ASC LIMIT 3;', function (error, results, fields) {
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error) ;
    });
    
      connection.query('SELECT table4.field1, table2.field2, table2.field3, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 0, 1) AS field4, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 1, 1) AS field5, \
                            (SELECT field1 FROM view_table LIMIT 2, 1) AS field6 \
                        FROM table2 \
                        JOIN table4 ON table2.id = table4.id \
                        WHERE table2.id = ?', event['param1'], function (error, results, fields) {
      // And done with the connection.
      connection.release();
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error) ;
      else callback(null, results);
    });
  });
};
```

The above would have you drop the view, and then perform the create view afterwards.

Comment: Nice and classic solution. But I am getting this minor "errorMessage": "Connection already released", when I tried to run it.

Comment: Ooh derp, accidently had two sets of connection release, updated answer :)

Comment: I tried that actually but a new error comes up "errorMessage": "ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT table4.name, container, size, (SELECT field1 FRO' at line 1", I am not sure if this SQL syntax related because this already on this query alone and it works. I think somewhere is triggering the error.

Comment: I supposed I am on the right track already. Just few more tweaks left here...

Comment: Ah right I see its 3 queries, not 2. This might cause syntax issues too.

Comment: Done! It was supposed to be 3 queries. I separated the create view query and now it works!

Comment: YEs I just updated in the answer too :). Glad I could help :)

Comment: Just right it time! hahaha... we got it! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! See you in some of my queries! I'll mark this as answered already. Thank you!

Comment: I just have a follow-up very quick question related to this. I am having multiple "?" in my current code. Here's my code: Qty = ? WHERE ID = ?;', event['qty', 'id'], function (error, results, fields). Is this the right was to do it?

Comment: If you have multiple `?` you'd need to list each one separately as far as I am aware  `Qty = ? WHERE ID = ?;', event['qty'], event['id'], function (error, results, fields)` however I have not used this library before so not 100% :)

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion but I am getting this error "errorMessage": "argument callback must be a function when provided"

Comment: Tried this also event['qty', 'id'] but no luck.

Comment: I've seen something like this event['qty']['id'] but also fails.

Comment: Try `Qty = ? WHERE ID = ?;', [event['qty'], event['id']], function (error, results, fields)`

Comment: Perfect! You really an Angel! Thank you so much. I'll raise another question here quickly and if you don't mind put this answer there? and I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Sure will do that

Comment: I just posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030217/right-syntax-for-multiple-input-event-params-in-aws-lambda-nodejs. Thanks.

Comment: Another relevant question and I hope you don't mind. From your answered code above, I want to pass an IF STATEMENT to whether I should run the query or not if the data already exist in the table. The data is represented by an ID as input event params.

Comment: I mean ID in the mysql table. So the code I am looking at is: If (ID = ?) {..here goes the above queries..}. I just really don't know the syntax for the (ID=?) and where to position in the code the event['id']. Hope you can help me..

Comment: Use `If Exists`, https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,356839

Comment: I'm trying to do it in NodeJs instead of another mysql query because I want them encapsulated with NodeJs IF STATEMENT to avoid running those queries in the first place if ID existed.

Comment: You would need to run the query seperately and then run an if based on results then :)

Comment: I've tried that already but I am having difficulty with NodeJS syntax on IF Statement. I have raised a question here — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083370/nodejs-if-statement-in-aws-lambda-using-mysql-database. You may want to check. Thanks.