# Right syntax for multiple input event params in AWS Lambda NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can anyone help me correct with this code in Lambda Nodejs with multiple input event params.

I've tried already the following but no luck!

```
ABC = ? WHERE XYZ = ?;', event['ABC', 'XYZ'], function (error, results, fields)

ABC = ? WHERE XYZ = ?;', event['ABC']['XYZ'], function (error, results, fields)

ABC = ? WHERE XYZ = ?;', event['ABC'], event['XYZ'], function (error, results, fields)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax that you should be using is below.

By doing this you're providing them as a list.

`event['ABC', 'XYZ']` is not valid syntax.

`event['ABC']['XYZ']` is looking for a `XYZ` key inside of `event['ABC']`.

`event['ABC'], event['XYZ']` is passing in to many parameters.

```
ABC = ? WHERE XYZ = ?;', [event['ABC'], event['XYZ']], function (error, results, fields)
```

Comment: No problem, have  a great day :)