# NodeJs IF Statement in AWS Lambda using MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass an IF statement (IF data exists in table, [true] update data, [false] insert data) in NodeJS for either of the following queries:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname
  });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

      // IF STATEMENT
      var id = ... //select statement to the same table...??
      If (id = ?) {

          // If TRUE
          connection.query('UPDATE table SET email = "'johndoe@icloud.com'" WHERE id = 1;', function (error, results, fields) {
          // And done with the connection.
          connection.release();
          // Handle error after the release.
          if (error) callback(error) ;
          else callback(null, results);,
 
          // If FALSE
          connection.query('INSERT INTO table (id, name, email) VALUES (1, "'John Doe'", "'johndoe@gmail.com'");', event['i'], function (error, results, fields) {
          // And done with the connection.
          connection.release();
          // Handle error after the release.
          if (error) callback(error) ;
          else callback(null, results);

      }; 
    });
  });
};
```

I am new to NodeJS and I am still trying to figure out the IF STATEMENT with the codes I have above. I will keep you posted.

**@CHRISWILLIAMS RESULTS DETAILS FOR HIS ANSWER**

Basically, I have 2 APIs.

The first API runs initially, drop canvass_prices if exists. This one I don't have any issue. Here's the result of the first API:

```
Response:
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Item": "Earth Science Deep Conditioning Masque For Hair - 2 Fl Oz",
    "Qty": 30,
    "Container": "Bottle",
    "Size": "750ml",
    "Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.": 1680,
    "Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.": 19920,
    "Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...": 79170
  }
]

Request ID:
"e2bbe38b-8121-4cb5-aa88-ac570b066759"

Function logs:
START RequestId: e2bbe38b-8121-4cb5-aa88-ac570b066759 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: e2bbe38b-8121-4cb5-aa88-ac570b066759
REPORT RequestId: e2bbe38b-8121-4cb5-aa88-ac570b066759  Duration: 287.67 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB
```

And this is the 2nd API (see my 1st update here) which I am having trouble with. This API will update the canvass_prices created by 1st API.

However, the first time I clicked the result is this:

```
Response:
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Item": "Earth Science Deep Conditioning Masque For Hair - 2 Fl Oz",
    "Qty": 30,
    "Container": "Bottle",
    "Size": "750ml",
    "Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.": 1680,
    "Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.": 19920,
    "Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...": 79170,
    "Voluptates laudantium voluptas nam.": null,
    "Ipsum voluptatem dolorum commodi.": null
  }
]

Request ID:
"4aed4c97-8ef6-485c-93b4-ca2eaf95703d"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 4aed4c97-8ef6-485c-93b4-ca2eaf95703d Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 4aed4c97-8ef6-485c-93b4-ca2eaf95703d
REPORT RequestId: 4aed4c97-8ef6-485c-93b4-ca2eaf95703d  Duration: 393.79 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 75 MB
```

The the second and subsequent clicks solves my issue, it returns the correct results and will not further return duplicate "ID".

```
Response:
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Item": "Earth Science Deep Conditioning Masque For Hair - 2 Fl Oz",
    "Qty": 30,
    "Container": "Bottle",
    "Size": "750ml",
    "Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.": 1680,
    "Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.": 19920,
    "Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...": 79170,
    "Voluptates laudantium voluptas nam.": null,
    "Ipsum voluptatem dolorum commodi.": null
  },
  {
    "ID": 9,
    "Item": "Laci Le Beau Maximum Strength Super Dieter's Tea Cinnamon Spice - 12 Tea Bags",
    "Qty": 10,
    "Container": "Bottle",
    "Size": "750ml",
    "Reiciendis eos nostrum ut sequi.": null,
    "Sed quidem aspernatur quisquam ut.": 30,
    "Aut dolorem repellendus iste nisi...": null,
    "Voluptates laudantium voluptas nam.": 1510,
    "Ipsum voluptatem dolorum commodi.": 17910
  }
]

Request ID:
"de40d4fa-06bb-433f-81d0-d667b2e2bca6"

Function logs:
START RequestId: de40d4fa-06bb-433f-81d0-d667b2e2bca6 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: de40d4fa-06bb-433f-81d0-d667b2e2bca6
REPORT RequestId: de40d4fa-06bb-433f-81d0-d667b2e2bca6  Duration: 70.41 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 75 MB
```

I wondering why it comes on the second click.

Comment: See your quoting, you've got a signle quote query string, with a quoted email. The quoted email ends the first string. Pay attention to the syntax highlighting. Use different quote styles, like double quotes `"` on the outside and single quotes on the inside. Flip if requirements changes.

Comment: Also use `insert ... on duplicate key update ..` and you won't be subject to race conditions.

Comment: Appreciate your advise. Other than the queries, I am having trouble with my nodejs code on IF STATEMENT with variable referred from the table.

Comment: If you use `insert ... on duplicate key udpate ...` you don't an IF STATEMENT. It will achieve the results if the results regardless. Are your email addresses intentionally different in this question? What do you want id equal to? Is this the same ID n the query?

Comment: @danblack Yes, the email addresses are exactly different. If the record exist then it needs update for email correction. If not, then it is inserted. However, that 2 queries are working already. My main issue is this part. I don't know how to do this right.
var id = ... //select statement to the same table...??
If (id == ?) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or without an if statement and a race conditions:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      connection.query('INSERT INTO table (id, name, email)
        VALUES (1, "John Doe", "johndoe@gmail.com")
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table email = "johndoe@icloud.com";', function (error, results, fields) {
          // And done with the connection.
          connection.release();
          // Handle error after the release.
          if (error) callback(error) ;
          else callback(null, results);
      }; 
    });
  });
```

This assumes `id` is a primary or unique key in the table.

Comment: I like your solution cleaner and direct but can you please check my solution in the update. I am having hard time figuring out where the error is coming from. Please bear I have share my exact codes in the update above.

Comment: This is a rather different question/problem all of a sudden. `INSERT` isn't a function that can be placed as a result to `CONCAT`, its a statement on iits own. Try asking again as a pure SQL question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with what you want to be inserted and some table structures. There are far too many `DISTINCT`s in your query and the user variable aspects look odd.  What mysql version you are targetting would help too.

Comment: I understand. Sorry about that. But the case here can be confined on what you suggested. There are prepared statement, execute, deallocate after which but I prefer not to show to isolate the error.

Comment: Clarification: Referring to your event['id'] you indicated in your solution, is it required as primary reference of the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Comment: remove `event[id]`, it was a mistake. The primary reference comes from the `id` in the `insert` part of the query.

Comment: Thank you. When I added the primary key on id which is actually created at runtime, it did prompt an error on duplicate record which is good! I suspect there is some minur syntax error somewhere. It should work already.

Comment: At last! Your answer works by removing the "table SET" and "event['i']". Kindly update your answer so I can mark it as Answered. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is specifically a NodeJS only answer then the problem is you are `=` rather than `==`. The single equals assigns Id to the value you're trying to compare to, whereas the double equals is the notation for is equal to. There's also `===` which presents as is identical to (`==` does not care for type so 5=='5' would be true, whereas fail for identical to).

Below is the fixed code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = require('./config.json');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname
  });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

      // IF STATEMENT
      connection.query('SELECT id from table where id = ?', [event['id']], function (error, results, fields) {
          if (results.length > 0) {

              // If TRUE
              connection.query('UPDATE table SET email = "'johndoe@icloud.com'" WHERE id = 1;', function (error, results, fields) {
              // And done with the connection.
              connection.release();
              // Handle error after the release.
              if (error) callback(error) ;
              else callback(null, results);,
     
              // If FALSE
              connection.query('INSERT INTO table (id, name, email) VALUES (1, "'John Doe'", "'johndoe@gmail.com'");', event['i'], function (error, results, fields) {
              // And done with the connection.
              connection.release();
              // Handle error after the release.
              if (error) callback(error) ;
              else callback(null, results);

          }; 
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: In this code if (id == ?) { how can I assign an event parameter just like what we did in the query. This ? is a variable that I assign as parameter.

Comment: You would just put the variable name, so for example if this came from event['id'] you would have `id == event['id']`

Comment: What! that's how easy it is? Let me get back to you. I will try now.

Comment: This assumes that id is a specific value you've post processed from your query

Comment: There's one left issue I haven't figure out — the var id =... ??
I know I have to pass the query here to select from the table the 'id' I was looking for.
I think on my IF Statement, I should be doing this instead.   IF ID EXISTS    but I do not know how to do it in NodeJS.

Comment: Have updated the code, I think this does exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you! I am almost there. No more error at design time except some minur syntax error at runtime. I'll get back to you. Let me figure this out.

Comment: Really almost there! But surprisingly, the result on the first run is TRUE and the second is FALSE. I am still trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you print results both times to see what’s being returned? :)

Comment: As requested, I have updated my question with result details. The mysterious part is the result comes after 2nd click. I am not sure if it has something to do with the variable query runs by PREPARED STATEMENT.

Comment: Though this is answered already by DanBlack, I'd to see your solution so I can mark it also as answered. Please feel free to get back if you have figure out that little issue left. Your solution is more classic and someone here in SO might refer to it. Otherwise, just let me know.